# Scaling JPanels with Miglayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have one large JPanel that can have 0-4 JPanels added to it as rows. 
I'm aiming to have the added Panels Scale to the size of the large Panel it's being added to (depending on how many panels are present) 
1 Panel = 100% of the Panel 
2 Panels = 50% of the Panel each 
3 Panels = 33% of the Panel each 
My jank solution was to divide the large panel into 12 set rows/cells (divisible by 3&4)

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("","[100%]","[8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%][8.3%]"));
```

and then depending on how many panels are added scale their span

```
if(count == 1){
 add(panel1, "cell 0 0, span 1 12, grow");
}
else if (count == 2){
add(panel1, "cell 0 0, span 1 6, grow");
add(panel2, "cell 0 6, span 1 6, grow");
...
...
```

This works... but is super ugly and I'm sure there must be an easier way.

Comment: Use a panel with a  `GridLayout`. This is exactly how it works and you don't need any fancy constraints.

Comment: @camickr I'm open GridLayout, but not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm open GridLayout, but not sure how to implement.

Why are you using the MigLayout when you don't even know how to use the basic layout managers provided in the JDK?

There is no trick. You create a panel, set the layout and add the components to the panel.

```
JPanel parent = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
parent.add(child1);
parent.add(child2);
,,,
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the basics of all the standard layout managers.